# SharePoint 2013 - Can we access "People and Groups" from LoginView RoleGroups?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within a .htm master template or .htm custom page layout, can we use the loginView RoleGroups to detect SharePoint Groups (under site settings)?

For example, if I create a user in SharePoint 2013, and assign them to group "Demo" from site settings, ...can I then detect that person's group on my page like this...

```
<!--SPM:                <RoleGroups>-->
<!--SPM:                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Demo">-->
<!--SPM:                        <ContentTemplate>-->
                                 <p>Display content for all people under Demo Group in SharePoint 2013!</p>
<!--SPM:                        </ContentTemplate>-->
<!--SPM:                    </asp:RoleGroup>-->
```

Is this possible? If not, how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2013 Security Trimming can be done for three types of Roles

1. Authors - Contribute Permission
2. Readers - View Permission
3. Full Control - Owner Permission

You can create Snippets (Design Manager) based on these roles and apply security on master page.

A sample snippet looks as below

```
<div data-name="SecurityTrimmedAuthors">
<!--CS: Start Security Trim Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly" Permissions="AddAndCustomizePages" PermissionContext="RootSite">-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="border:medium black solid; background:yellow; color:black; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
    You should replace this div with content that renders based on your Security Trim Properties.
    </div>
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--></span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
<!--CE: End Security Trim Snippet-->
```

Permission takes one of the following values

1. AddAndCustomizePages
2. ViewPages
3. FullMask

More details can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822366(v=office.15).aspx

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/190/Security-Trim-Snippet-in-SharePoint-2013,-Add-Security-trim-snippet-to-a-master-page

**Update Based on Robert's suggestion**

1. Browse to your publishing site.
2. In the upper-right corner of the page, choose the Settings gear, and then choose Design Manager.
3. In Design Manager, in the left navigation pane, choose Edit Master Pages or Edit Page Layouts, depending on what type of file you're editing.
4. Select the name of the master page or page layout that you want to add the snippet to.
   To open the Snippet Gallery, choose Snippets in the upper-right corner of the server-side preview.
5. Choose the webpart from the Ribbon (Media Content -> Content Editor)
6. From Right Side Properties Expand "Advanced"
7. Enter "Target Audiences" (Click on Browse, type the group name and select)
8. Click Update
9. Copy the HTML Snippet and use it in your page layout.

Comment: In SharePoint 2013, you can create any Group you want,  under Users and Groups.  I simply want to reference the Group onto my custom page layout and display special content just for that group.

Comment: Use the role of the group for doing that. For example if you want to display some part for Group A then make sure the group has a specific set of permission (View/Contribute/Full) and use that in your snippet

Comment: I'm not looking to see if yo are an author, reader or full control user, I am looking to see if you belong to Group (police), or group (music artist), or group (atheletes), etc...these users are not sharepoint administrators, they simply have different HTML content displayed on the custom page layout, depending on what SharePoint group they are in...like different types of "Readers"

Comment: You can use audiences on Webparts for this (you find it in the webpart settings)

Comment: thank you Robert! this is getting me closer to my end goal. Can you point in to any recommended tutorials on using Audiences in SharePoint 2013?  I'm diving into this for the first time.  (i.e. can I create my Audience in SharePoint 2013 from the  browser and use it as a snippet?)

Comment: Here's a guide for creating them in 2010, but it is very similar for 2013: https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/chirag-mehta/2013/07/25/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-audience#.VElUL4heCK0. You should be able to use (ad) groups without creating specific audiences as well

Comment: Crap!  We need the user profile service turned on!  I can't do that from my end...

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can use the Client Side Object Module to access the Group number associated to the SharePoint Group that the user is a part of, and simply send JavaScript to the page if that Group Id exist!  On success, you can create and attach a class to an existing element with an ID with JavaScript, then display block or display none, etc...from your style sheet.

Not a secure sever side solution, but an easy client side quick fix solution.